# app freezes when opened, Phonegap alerts not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, freeze

At very first launch of my app from the home screen, everything works fine - no freezing.

When I use the app at a later time, suddenly when I tap it from the home screen, sometimes it will freeze for 5 seconds (i.e. just stays on the home screen), and then it loads. This isn't the end of the story.

The app doesn't freeze every time after the first load; however, once it starts freezing from the home screen, it it will continue to do this until I Force Stop the app.

After it freezes like this, some Phonegap functionality doesn't work. For example, navigator.notification.alert fades the background, but no popup appears. The only way to exit is to tap the phone's back button.

How can I stop the app from freezing at opening, thereby causing other Phonegap functionality to stop working properly?

(This is Phonegap 2.9.0; however, I had the same issues 2.5.0)

**All help is appreciated, thank you**

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. When my app is installed on a device, and I wait 3-4 hours and start the app again, it freezes. The alert `document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
try {alert('Device is ready!'); ...` is not triggered. The app freezes (doesn't crash). Happens with phonegap 2.7 and 2.4.

Comment: @binoculars does your app use AdMob? Mine does. I'm trying to figure out if that's part of the problem.

Comment: My app does not use AdMob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", false);
```

right before `super.loadUrl` in your main .java-file worked for me.

In the meantime, due to many (!) hours of debugging, my app has an overload on "possible bug fixes". I think the code above is the real fix, but here are some other changes I made:

Added to main .java-file (before `super.loadUrl`):

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

Added to the android manifest (in the application tag):

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

**Edit:**

Also, try using these settings in your android manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to mark this as correct. However I wasn't having this issue anymore for some reason; but I did set `keepRunning` to `false` in config.xml just in case